# Get month of a given date

Tags: php

Get month of a given date which is stored in a PHP time variable in 'Y-m-d' format

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try [`date_parse_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php):

```
$date = "2010-08-12";
$d = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $date);
echo $d["month"];
```

Answer (score 32):

```
$date = "2010-10-10";
echo date("m", strtotime($date))?>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$parts = explode('-',$your_date_variable_in_php);
$month = $parts[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

is it really stored in PHP? Not in some database?
`month(datefield)` can do it in mysql query for example

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date("F", strtotime("2010-08-13"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
<?php
    $date = "2010-08-13";
    echo date("m",strtotime($date))."\n";
?>
```