# PHP get the current month of a date

Tags: php, date

Hello everybody I would like to get the current month of a date.

This is what I tried:

```
<?php 

   $transdate = date('m-d-Y', time());

   echo $transdate;

   $month = date('m', strtotime($transdate));

   if ($month == "12") {
       echo "<br />December is the month :)";
   } else {
       echo "<br /> The month is probably not December";
   }

?>
```

But the result is wrong, it should display December is the month :0

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Why  you don't run the second date with function with the time() as a second parameter and you run it two times ? :?

Comment: `if($month == 12)`. 12 should be integer not string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get month of a given date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474315/get-month-of-a-given-date)

Comment: switch the else and if

Comment: @raheelshan `date()` returns a string, so you better not wrap 12 in quotes. BTW, when comparing string "12" and interger 12 with `==` operator, PHP will ignore data type and regard them as the same. `===` operator would be more strict.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to use the default date() function of PHP to get current month. Then you can easily check it by if conditions as mentioned in the code below:

```
<?php 
$month = date('m');

if($month == 12){
   echo "<br />December is the month :)";
} else {
   echo "<br /> The month is probably not December";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 11):

Why not simply

```
echo date('F, Y');
```

? This prints November, 2017.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you use the function [idate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idate.php), which returns an integer rather than a formatted string.

```
$month = idate("m");
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a much better way of doing this

```
echo date("F", strtotime('m'));
```

Comment: this is a more solid answer

Comment: Thank you Albuquerque, remember to upvote too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $transdate = date('m-d-Y', time());

      $d = date_parse_from_format("m-d-y",$transdate);



     $month = $d["month"];

      if($month == "12"){

    echo "December is the month :)";
       } else {
    echo "The month is probably not December";
       }
?>
```

Comment: probably doesn't inspire confidence, but it's so realistic - since date could easily be spoofed! :D that's great

Answer (score 0):

I can see some time has passed since this post but currently the best way of working with dates is picking the right lettering from the table that PHP has:
[datetime.format.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

You can get just the month with lowercase n:

```
date('n')
```

Here are all  the month options:

1. F   A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March  January through December
2. m   Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through
   12
3. M   A short textual representation of a month, three letters    Jan
   through Dec
4. n   Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros    1 through
   12
5. t   Number of days in the given month   28 through 31